# CMD Find and Replace with User input with xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am in need of some help.  I have a batch file that randomly creates names for any set.
This all works well as it should.

I also have the batch program to read an xml file to pull specific nodes within the xml.  What I need to do is have the batch update the xml node with the pre selected random names.

here is some of my code:

```
::Start Random Names

Set EBSTA1=%Random%
if /i %EBSTA1% GTR 11 goto EBSTA
If /i %EBSTA1% LSS 1 goto EBSTA
goto Weststa1
:Weststa1
If %EBSTA1% == 1 set EBSTA2=NEBO
If %EBSTA1% == 2 set EBSTA2=YR
If %EBSTA1% == 3 set EBSTA2=DV
If %EBSTA1% == 4 set EBSTA2=BAR
If %EBSTA1% == 5 set EBSTA2=BOR
If %EBSTA1% == 6 set EBSTA2=MOJ
If %EBSTA1% == 7 set EBSTA2=PPG
If %EBSTA1% == 8 set EBSTA2=PAR
If %EBSTA1% == 9 set EBSTA2=BAK
If %EBSTA1% == 10 set EBSTA2=EDW
If %EBSTA1% == 11 set EBSTA2=TEH
```

of course I have it echoing out %EBSTA2%

here is my find and replace, which works sort of..

```
set str=%EBSTA2%
Echo. %str%
set str=%str:%%EBSTA2% 
Echo %str%
(
Echo(^<destinationTag^>%str%^</destinationTag^>
)>>"test.xml"
```

what would be the way to update the destinationTag with the new string from the random?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify your question. You script seems to be doing what you are asking. The only caveat is that %Random% returns a number between 0 and 32767. You will not get something between 1 an 11 often...

Comment: if I run the program, it will set 1-11 as a variable, and assign what ever EBSTA2 would be.  

That part is fine, and the find and replace is working correctly. but what I need to do is dynamiclly update the complete XML.

the xml could have up to 100 <destinationTag>*</destinationTag> within, so how could I set up a batch file to cycle through the entire xml and update with %EBSTA2%?